# nginx SSL configuration Using cer files

Tags: nginx

I would like configure SSL for nginx using certificates . Iam new to Nginx and security stuff. I was given a .cer file and asked to  configure SSL in Nginx. I googled for certain examples but found most of them used either csr and crt files. Can any one guide me on how to configure ssl using the .cer extension files.

What needs to be added for ssl_certificate elements in nginx configration if i have .cer files

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `.cer` file as long as it is PEM formatted. See [configuring HTTPS servers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) for guidance.

Conversion from DER to PEM can be accomplished using [this website](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html).

Comment: Thank you very much Richard.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by getting the key from our security team.

Thanks for all responses